# How do I uninstall the chaincode installed on HyperLedger

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I have installed chaincode fine, but when I want to uninstall the same chaincode from the machine how I will do it? please help me.

I have used the command below to install

```
peer chaincode install -n <chaincodename> -v 0 -p <chaincode path>
```

what would be the uninstall command?

Comment: you can not uninstall chaincode, you can upgrade the chaincode to higher version, so it will disable the use of previous chaincode.

Comment: the upgrade is the instantiation, I am asking about uninstall completely that particular chaincode.

Answer (score 1):

For Fabric 2.x

1. Kill the chaincode container using command
   `docker rm -f <chaincode container id>`
2. Delete the chaincode from the file system of the peer under
   **/var/hyperledger/production/lifecycle/chaincodes**
3. Restart your **peer** container.

PS. After restarting the peer container all your chaincode containers will be restarted wait till all the containers are up.

Comment: @jagtap, thank you for replying to me. can't we uninstall without restart the container? I have installed number of versions all the versions im seeing so that i need to uninstall few installed smartcontracts.

Comment: @Vijay The above process completely removes the installed chaincodes. if you don't restart the peer container, you will get all installed chaincodes names whenever you do query.

Comment: thanks @jagtap, okay got it. but my question is, is it possible that can we uninstall any one particular smart contract that i dont want?

Answer (score 0):

In fabric there is no such command for uninstalling the chaincode but you can manually remove the previous chaincode from your peer containers by following the mentioned steps.

1. login to your container

> docker exec -it <peer_container_name> sh

2. remove the previous installed chaincodes from containers

> rm /var/hyperledger/production/lifecycle/chaincodes/*

3. exit from container and restart the container

> exit
>
> docker restart <peer_container_name>

you can verify it by running queryinstalled command

> peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled